# Solution verification using Fubini-Tonelli

Tags: real-analysis

I have a solution to the following problem and was wondering if my solution is correct. Let $T \in \mathbb{R} : T > 0$. Let $f : (0,T) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an $L^{1}$ function. Define $g(x) = \int_{x}^{T} \frac{f(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t$. Show that $\int_{0}^{T} g(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{T} f(t) \mathrm{d}t$. First suppose that $f(t) \geq 0 , \forall t \in (0,T)$. Then by Tonelli's Theorem: $\int_{0}^{T} g(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{T} \int_{x}^{T} \frac{f(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{T} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{f(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{T} f(t) \mathrm{d}t$. Suppose that $f : (0,T) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not necessarily non-negative. Then $f = f^{+} - f^{-}$ such that $f^{+}, f^{-}$ are non-negative functions. Define $g^{+} = \int_{x}^{T} \frac{f^{+}(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t$, and $g^{-}$ respectively. Then $\int_{0}^{T} g(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{T} (g^{+}  - g^{-}) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{T} f^{+}(t) \mathrm{d}t  - \int_{0}^{T} f^{-}(t) \mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{T} f(t) \mathrm{d}t$, by applying Tonelli's Theorem to $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$ accordingly. My main question is whether my application of Tonelli's Theorem was correct, and whether I am allowed to generalize to $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$.

Comment: Why don't you use Fubini theorem for the second part of the proof? In the first part you see that $f(t)/t$ is integrable and so you can use it. This, you would not need to think about positive and negative functions

Comment: I am unclear about how to apply Fubini's Theorem. Is it that if $\int_{X_{1}} \int_{X_{2}} |f| d \mu_{2} d \mu_{1} < \infty$, then $\int_{X_{1}} \int_{X_{2}} f d \mu_{2} d \mu_{1} = \int_{X_{2}} \int_{X_{1}} f d \mu_{1} d \mu_{2}$. Is it that if the integral of the absolute value of the function is finite for some ordering then we may switch the order of integration? Also, does my solution hold the way it is now?